# How To Represent foreign key in Entity Framework's POCO Class

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I noticed something when i was reading through some Entity Framework's POCO classes that the one to many relationship is always represented in two ways like following :

```
1- Public List<User> Users {get;set;}
2- Public Virtual User Users {get;set}
```

So which one is right and when i should use each, this concept really confused me !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've read that wrong. Typically (although not required), you would have navigation properties at both ends of the relationship.

A collection navigation property on the *one* side (a `Department` may have a `List<User>` for example) and a reference navigation property on the *many* side (a `User` would have one `Department`).

It is also recommended that you have a foreign key property as well, for example an `int DepartmentId` on the `User`.

You would need to mark the navigation properties as `virtual` if you wanted to support lazy loading. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/dd468057%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the requirements on POCO types.

Comment: That was very helpful,and straight to the point, very helpful respond